# Android Animation/Transition like Google maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, fragment, transition

Does somebody knows how to create Fragment Transitions like in the newest update of the google maps app? [Here is the google maps app example how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3crj.gif)

Comment: i used a bottom sheet to get the content from the bottom to top. the action bar stays the same in my case